# Shorthand approach to writing a long list of if statements

Tags: ms-access, combobox, vba, ms-access-2010

Is there a shorthand approach to writing this big block of code?

What I have currently works - but its proving to be a pain in the backside to maintain.

```
If cboOption1 = "bp" And cboOption5 = "cs" Then
    Valid = False
    MsgBox ("You can not select bp and cs")

ElseIf cboOption1 = "bp" And cboOption6 = "cs" Then
    Valid = False
    MsgBox ("You can not select bp and cs"))

ElseIf cboOption1 = "bp" And cboOption7 = "cs" Then
    Valid = False
    MsgBox ("You can not select bp and cs")

ElseIf cboOption1 = "bp" And cboOption8 = "cs" Then
    Valid = False
    MsgBox ("You can not select bp and cs")

ElseIf cboOption2 = "bp" And cboOption5 = "cs" Then
    Valid = False
    MsgBox ("You can not select bp and cs")

ElseIf cboOption2 = "bp" And cboOption6 = "cs" Then
    Valid = False
    MsgBox ("You can not select bp and cs")

ElseIf cboOption2 = "bp" And cboOption7 = "cs" Then
    Valid = False
    MsgBox ("You can not select bp and cs")

ElseIf cboOption2 = "bp" And cboOption8 = "cs" Then
    Valid = False
    MsgBox ("You can not select bp and cs")

ElseIf cboOption3 = "bp" And cboOption5 = "cs" Then
    Valid = False
    MsgBox ("You can not select bp and cs")

ElseIf cboOption3 = "bp" And cboOption6 = "cs" Then
    Valid = False
    MsgBox ("You can not select bp and cs")

ElseIf cboOption3 = "bp" And cboOption7 = "cs" Then
    Valid = False
    MsgBox ("You can not select bp and cs")

ElseIf cboOption3 = "bp" And cboOption8 = "cs" Then
    Valid = False
    MsgBox ("You can not select bp and cs")

ElseIf cboOption4 = "bp" And cboOption5 = "cs" Then
    Valid = False
    MsgBox ("You can not select bp and cs")

ElseIf cboOption4 = "bp" And cboOption6 = "cs" Then
    Valid = False
    MsgBox ("You can not select bp and cs")

ElseIf cboOption4 = "bp" And cboOption7 = "cs" Then
    Valid = False
    MsgBox ("You can not select bp and cs")

ElseIf cboOption4 = "bp" And cboOption8 = "cs" Then
    Valid = False
    MsgBox ("You can not select bp and cs")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First use a constant to hold the `MsgBox` text ... it's the same every time.

Then you can use nested `For ... Next` loops to cycle through your target combo box pairs.

```vb
Const cstrPrompt As String = "You can not select bp and cs"
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long

For i = 1 To 4
    For j = 5 To 8
        If Me.Controls("cboOption" & i).Value = "bp" _
                And Me.Controls("cboOption" & j).Value = "cs" Then
             Valid = False
             MsgBox cstrPrompt
        End If
    Next
Next
```

Note that will display a `MsgBox` for each pair of invalid values.  If you want to display a notice for only the first invalid pair and then stop, you would have break out of the `For` loops.

Comment: Fantastic - will reference this for future use. Thank you.